# SQL - Select value with newest date

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to select added value "state" with newest date from my table, but only if left join table object is visible. And only once per property and unit in.
What i have done so far:

```sql
SELECT propertyUnitEnergyStates.id,
       propertyUnitEnergyStates.property_id,
       propertyUnitEnergyStates.unit_id,
       propertyUnitEnergyStates.type,
       propertyUnitEnergyStates.state,
       propertyUnitEnergyStates.date,
       propertyUnits.visible
  FROM propertyUnitEnergyStates
  LEFT JOIN propertyUnits
    ON propertyUnits.property_id = $propertyID
 WHERE propertyUnitEnergyStates.property_id = $propertyID
   AND propertyUnitEnergyStates.type = '$name'
   AND propertyUnits.visible = 1
 GROUP BY propertyUnitEnergyStates.unit_id
 ORDER BY propertyUnitEnergyStates.date DESC
```

What I am getting now is result where every propertyUnits.visible is 1. Even if in table is set to zero.
[image]

Object from propertyUnits. As you can see the value visible is 0 but i am getting 1.
[image]

Right now i noticed that, the "state" value which i want to be the newest is not the newest.

[image]

As you can see i have in my result for unit_id 5 value 853, but in the table propertyUnitEnergyStates is the newest value 400.

Comment: Please post data as text not images.

Comment: I see. At first, The order by clause is executed after the group by clause. So... you can't get the newest state from this query. you have to get newest status before left join. Let me check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Let's try like this.

```
WITH ranked_state AS (
  SELECT us.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY unit_id ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
  FROM propertyUnitEnergyStates us
  WHERE us.type = '$name' AND us.property_id = $propertyID
)
SELECT ranked_state.id, 
       ranked_state.property_id, 
       ranked_state.unit_id, 
       ranked_state.type, 
       ranked_state.state, 
       ranked_state.date, 
       pu.visible 
FROM ranked_state 
LEFT JOIN propertyUnits pu
ON ranked_state.property_id = pu.property_id AND pu.visible = 1
WHERE rn = 1
```

If I explain this query.. First, regarding the rows that meet the given condition(ex: `us.type="$name", us.property_id=$propertyID`), the rows with the same `unit_id` are `ordered by date`.
After then do LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Looks good, but i cannot use WITH in my mariaDB.. I am using Ver 10.3.27 MariaDB

Comment: what is your DB version? This will work from 10.2.1

Comment: I see. Now it worked, but it returns weird values, after every start. The values always differ and it seems it ignoring property ids

Comment: Hm.. I can't explain exactly why it's returning a strange value since the reason that I can't test it, but I'm trying to you can refer to this logic.

Answer (score 0):

I try different options, but I still can't get the result. It still ignores the visible attribute and does not return the last record by date.

Here is my last try:

```
$query = "SELECT UniEne.id, 
        UniEne.property_id, 
        UniEne.unit_id, 
        UniEne.type, 
        UniEne.state, 
        UniEne.date, 
        propUni.visible 
        FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM propertyUnitEnergyStates WHERE type = '$name' AND property_id = $propertyID ORDER BY date DESC) AS UniEne 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM propertyUnits WHERE property_id= $propertyID AND visible = 1) as propUni
        WHERE UniEne.property_id = $propertyID GROUP BY UniEne.unit_id";
```

Result is:
[image]

But value "state" is not correct. The last inserted have in unit_id(1) value 7000..